# Get And Set Session In Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, session

I have Web Service Which handle Login And Logout , In web Service i set session Value and Get Session.In Log in

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public object LoginByEmail(string Email, string Password, int RegionID)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid? UserID = null;

            int? res = TBll.LoginByEmail(ref UserID, Email, Password, RegionID);

            if (res == 1)
                return new { Result = resultEnum.notcorrectemailorpassword };

            else if (res == 2)
            {
                Session["User"] = UserID;
                return new { Result = resultEnum.ok, UserID = UserID };
            }




            else if (res == 3)
                return new { Result = resultEnum.accountnotactive };
            else

                return new { Result = resultEnum.error };

        }
        catch
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.error };
        }

    }
```

When I Go to Definition in Session ( Session["User"] = UserID;) In Previous Code
[image: Session Property]

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public object CheckIfLoggedin()
    {
        try
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.ok, Records = GetUserID() };

        }
        catch
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.error };
        }

    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    private Guid? GetUserID()
    {

        if (Context.Session["User"] != null)
        {
            string userid = Context.Session["User"].ToString();
            if (userid != "")
                return new Guid(userid);
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return null;

    }
```

in Get I Use Context.Session(  string userid = Context.Session["User"].ToString();) if i go to Definition

[image]

My question Is What is the different between both? and what is the right Property Using to set and get session in web service ?

Comment: Using session for authentication is not recommended, you can use FormsAuthentication for authentication.

Comment: i can't use  FormsAuthentication  ,  i need to use Web service  and i call it use js

Comment: Session also uses cookies and FormsAuthentication also uses cookies, so if your client supports cookies then you can definitely use FormsAuthentication, FormsAuthentication does not mean you need ASP.NET form or some html form to process, it simply uses encrypted cookies for authentication. Session is also bad for scaling, but authentication can be setup for multiple web servers with load balancing.